# Can't access into other movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

I can't access in other movieclips, for example I have my sections "home", "about", "contact" and the labels in the sections.

When I go inside about and call the contact section to set the text for example
`_parent.instancename(contact).title.text = "TEST"`, I call this inside the about section but it doesn't work.

I put all the sections inside one movieclip called sections and inside the movieclip I have the labels for each section for example:

Layer 1 - actions (stops);
Layer 2 - labels (home, about, contact);
Layer 3 - movieclips (ho, ab, co);

Comment: What are these "sections"? Are they different frames, MovieClips, etc?

Comment: Yes I put all the sections inside one movieclip called sections and inside the movieclip I have the labels for each section for example Layer 1 - actions (stops); Layer 2 - labels (home, about, contact); Layer 3 - movieclips (ho, ab, co);

Comment: It maybe that the symbol you're calling from one MovieClip doesn't exist since it was removed from memory when the frame changed.

Comment: Do you want a example I can send you, it's very important to me

Answer (score 1):

As John Giotta said in his comment: When you change the frame by calling `gotoAndPlay ("Framelabel")`, all the elements in the frame you were in before are erased from memory.  So there will not be anything to access, when you try to change the text.

One way to do it is to put all your elements into separate MovieClips and place them in the same frame on the timeline, setting the active element to `visible = true;` and the others to `visible = false;` instead of jumping to another frame, when a button is clicked.
That way, you can access everything from everywhere, and your site will look just the same.